# Where is the location of the reflected impedence?

Tags: transformer

[image]

If I want represent the reflected impedance where should I put it in the circuit ?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't put it anywhere. It's not a part, it's a property of your circuit. For example  you can have a resistor as a load in the secondary of a transformer. In the primary one can measure an impedance which is affected by the resistor and the properties of the transformer. We can call that impedance "reflected impedance" because it is how the rest of the circuit see your resistor through the transformer.

You can insert a text label near the transformer primary connection Rload is seen as reflected impedance =.....

ADD after the question was edited to have an image:

If you still want to put the reflected impedance somewhere as a component, draw a box with two wires and replace with it everything which is to the right from points a and b. Write quite a complex formula in the box. The formula contains frequency, M, L1, L2, R1, R2 and ZL. The formula starts with "Z="

If ZL=0 it a little simplifies the formula, but surely frequency, M, L1, L2, R1 and  R2 are still there and it should still start with "Z="

Comment: I know, but if Z_L = 0 ohm, then how there is still a current there?

Comment: zero ohm isn't an obstacle for current. The rest of the circuit determines it. We actually use wires to connect our parts together and hope them to be as near as possible zero ohms.

Comment: I know, but I mean Vcd=0V if the resistor is zero how? Please see the picture